# Loop for string entry and reversal

Tags: java, loops, reverse, do-while, palindrome

I am trying to receive a string, cut off the first letter, place it at the end of the string, and compare it to the original input.  For some words it works and others it does not.  I am not sure if this is a problem with the loop or what?

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Palin{

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
          String original,input;
          Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Enter word and I will tell you if it has the property of a palindrome: ");
          original = sc.nextLine();
          char firstLetter = original.charAt(0);
          input = original.substring(1);
          input = input + firstLetter;
          StringBuilder input2=new StringBuilder(input).reverse();
          String s2=new String(input2);

          do{

            if(original.equals(s2))
                System.out.println(original + " is a Palindrome");
            else
                System.out.println(original + " is not a Palindrome");
                System.out.println("Enter another word. Or enter \"quit\" to end");
                original = sc.nextLine();
            } while (!(original.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")));

       }

}
```

Comment: If you have a look at related questions on the right side, you will find the solution. And I think it was a suggested duplicate when you were writing the question.

Comment: You are actually testing if the word is a palindrome AFTER the first letter. You could just write a test for that. It would be simpler.

Comment: StringBuilder input2=new StringBuilder(input).reverse();  this command does not reverse the whole string?

Comment: what words does it work for and what words does it not?

Comment: yes, that does reverse it. But you already changed the original by moving the first character to the end.

Comment: Correct Peter, I didn't think of that.

Comment: I am still having some difficulty adjusting my code.

Comment: I think the issue is more around the loop, because I am able to get the correct answer on the first try every time, but all subsequent entires just repeat the result of the first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just had to cleanup references and location of the do-while.  Thanks for the help.!

Output

Enter word and I will tell you if it has the property of a palindrome: 
Palindrome
Palindrome does not have a Palindrome property
Enter another word. Or enter "quit" to end
uneven
uneven has a Palindrome property
Enter another word. Or enter "quit" to end
banana
banana has a Palindrome property
Enter another word. Or enter "quit" to end
dresser
dresser has a Palindrome property
Enter another word. Or enter "quit" to end
quit

Revised code below.

import java.util.*;
        public class Palin{

```
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
          String original,input;
          Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Enter word and I will tell you if it has the property of a      palindrome: ");
          original = sc.nextLine();

        do{

          char firstLetter = original.charAt(0);
          input = original.substring(1);
          input = input + firstLetter;

          StringBuilder input2=new StringBuilder(input).reverse();
          String s2=new String(input2);



            if(original.equals(s2))
                System.out.println(original + " has a Palindrome property");
            else
                System.out.println(original + " does not have a Palindrome property");
                System.out.println("Enter another word. Or enter \"quit\" to end");
                original = sc.nextLine();
            } while (!(original.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")));

       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check only String is palindrome or not you can try something like:

```
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = s.nextLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    String rev = sb.reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(rev);
    if(str.equals(rev)){
        System.out.println("equal");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not equal");
    }
```

for the case sensitivity of string use String API.